# Using apply() in R to count the number of cells within a range for each column

Tags: r, apply

I have a large data frame containing numbers between 0 and 1 for which I am trying to count the number of values between 0.4 and 0.6 for each columns. I've successfully calculated the mean, median, etc. using apply to output a vector containing column means:

```
column_mean <- apply(x, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But I can't quite figure out how to modify `apply()` to count the number of values that fall within a range. I'm thinking something like this, but across all columns:

```
column_counts <- apply(x, 2, sum(x$c1 > 0.4 & x$c1 < 0.6), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use `colSums` : `column_counts <- colSums(x > 0.4 & x < 0.6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer:

```
> df <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10),
+                  Col2 = rnorm(10),
+                  Col3 = rnorm(10))
> df
          Col1       Col2       Col3
1   0.73804784  1.7342752 -1.0906748
2   1.65272822 -1.2936601  0.4721306
3   0.41988220  0.1148715 -0.3010973
4   0.19199975  1.2164140  0.7646785
5   0.09016752 -1.7179874 -0.5046282
6  -1.59440039  1.2948078 -0.3152287
7  -0.74238335 -0.6169977  0.8392895
8   0.28572911  0.8212279  0.5394922
9  -1.71357200  2.0856380  0.3221748
10 -0.29211236  0.5290523  0.4206429
> sapply(df, function(x) sum(x > 0.4 & x < 0.6))
Col1 Col2 Col3 
   1    1    3 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom function:

```
count_interval <- function(x) { 
  return(length(x[!is.na(x) & x>0.4 & x<0.6])) 
}
```

and then use it as before:

```
column_counts <- apply(x, 2, count_interval)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint first, you should supply an exemple for us to work with, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

You could create a function that makes that specific test, and then pass it to apply:

```
test = function(a){sum(a>=0.4 & a<=0.6)}
column_counts = apply(x, 2, test)
```